# Is there a white-label video-on-demand platform for educational content, that is not course based?

Tags: cloud-service, saas

I have a client, who wants to sell online videos to his community. This is educational content, but it's always only one huge 3-4 hour video per topic. I was hoping to find a quick solution and found platforms like Thinkific, LearnWorld and Teachable.

However, all those platforms are course based, meaning that I first create a course that can be sold and then I would add videos to it that are included in the paid course. This would look very unprofessional.

I'm looking for a platform on which my client can sell videos, but it needs to look professional and should support custom branding. It should also support coupons or custom currencies.

The initial idea was to use WordPress with MasterStudy plugin, but we decided to host this media library somewhere else for better performance, security and reachability. We also need a fast solution, no time for custom development.

EDIT: I found and tested [Uscreen](https://www.uscreen.tv/) that really fulfills all our expectations. However, it's very expensive. True white labeling costs 1k USD per month (no branding in the footer) and the whole software has hidden costs all over the place that do not appear on their landing page. So I'm looking for something like [Uscreen](https://www.uscreen.tv/), but it should be affordable.